# Akka: how to print body of HTTP 400 Error

Tags: java, akka

My HTTPS request to remove server failed with 400 status code. How do I capture and log the body of the response? Currently, my app just logs something like this

> org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https://{remote host}/{some path} with statusCode: 400

Comment: The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server (e.g. a request to load a web page) was somehow malformed therefore the server was unable to understand or process the request.  The request failed, so there's no response